# Multiple form submits from one button?

Tags: php, html, forms

How can I have multiple forms `SUBMITTED/POSTED` to PHP with one submit button? Is there an easy html way to achieve this? I need to use traditional `$_POST` variable on the PHP side that's why.

Example

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

    // SOme fields

</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

    // SOme more fields

</form>


<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

    // some fields here

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Stuff</button> // This button posts all three forms!
</form>
```

Comment: A downvote in less than 10 seconds? how is that even possible?

Comment: No, a submit is only going to work for the form in which it is nested. You're going to need ajax. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563299/submit-multiple-forms-with-one-submit-button

Comment: Why do you need three forms on a page? This seems like a bad idea. Why can't you just post all the fields in one form?

Comment: Issue is my other fields are in a modal. Modals need to stay on top of the page and so I can't just ad them in to the form.

Comment: Why not? Group them into a fieldset or a div, and use that for your modal …

Comment: @CBroe if I put my modals inside form, my page starts looking really funky.

Comment: To literally submit multiple forms, you need AJAX. Period. But I almost guarantee that if you are wanting to submit multiple 'sets' of data at once, you can do it otherwise.

Comment: Multiple sets of data that are not contained in form markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
<form class = "form-horizontal" method = "post>
    <select id = "select" name = "selection">
        <option name = "option_one" value = "html">html</option>
        …
    </select>

    <input type = "checkbox" name = "selected[]" value = "first_value">first</input>
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "selected[]" value = "second_value">second</input>

    <input type = "checkbox" name = "another_selected[]" value = "new_first">another first</input>
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "another_selected[]" value = "new_second">another second</input>
    <input id = "submit" name = "submit" type = "submit"></input>
</form>
```

Then in PHP:

```
$selected = _POST["select"];
$first_checkbox_group = _POST["selected"];
$second_checkbox_group = _POST["another_selected"];
```

Just make sure you give you different sections different names.

Comment: I think I clearly said I want to have three forms...

Comment: I'll upvote for the effort.