# how to submit two forms with a single click on one of their action button?

Tags: post, action, form-submit

I need an help on How to submit 2 form's POST methods both
with a one single click.
Suppose that I have two seperate forms 
I want my secound form to be submited at the time I click on the first form action button.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563299/submit-multiple-forms-with-one-submit-button

Comment: It is definitely a duplicate

Comment: Yes looks like it is a duplicate! :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with Javascript
first place a button that is going to submit both forms like this in your html

```
<button type="submit" class='input_submit' style="margin-right: 15px;" onClick="submitBothForms()">submit both</button>
```

then your submitBothForm method has to includes these lines

```
document.forms["first_form_name"].submit();

document.forms["secound_form_name"].submit();
```