# How can set value with selectBooleanCheckbox and Delete?

Tags: jsf, form-submit

I am doing a mini jsf project that is created by using jpa. I have listed costumers and I can remove them one by one, but if I want to remove selected costumers I cannot do it.

This part is from Costumer class

```
@Transient
private Boolean selection = false;
```

And this part is from CostumerBean

```
Costumer costumer = new Costumer();

private List<Costumer> costumerList = new ArrayList<>();
//(getters and setters)

public void removeSelected() {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    for (Costumer cos : costumerList) {
        if (cos.getSelection()) {

em.remove(em.contains(costumer) ? customer : em.merge(costumer));       
        }

    }

    em.getTransaction().commit();

    musteri = new Musteri();
}
```

And finally here is the xhtml page :

```
<h:form id="firstForm">

<p:commandButton action="#{customerBean.removeSelection}" value="Remove"
        update="customerForm">
</p:commandButton>
</h:form id="firstForm">


<h:form id="customerForm">

    <p:dataTable value="#{customerBean.customerList}" var="cst"
        id="cstTable">

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Select</f:facet>
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cst.selection}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
            #{cst.name}
        </p:column>
</h:form id="customerForm">
```

I reckon actual problem is I cannot make selection field in Costumer.java true. No action I see.?

Comment: I have no idea what this line trying to do `em.remove(em.contains(costumer) ? musteri : em.merge(costumer));`

Comment: it removes the customer object.

Comment: I know it is for safe remove but you should do something like this: `em.remove(em.contains(cos) ? cos : em.merge(cos));` because you are in a for loop and working with only `cos` object.

Comment: Maybe, but problem is different. When I debug it, I can not evet come this line. It cannot pass the if block. Becuase my <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cst.selection}" /> do not change selection.

Comment: Set the commandButton into the same form as the datatable. The CommandButton is only sending the files in the form by default

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @Raphael_S it wroked. Do you know how I can access different form? Is it possible?

Comment: I did not know what is really about so I added those tags @Kukeltje Thanks for the link

Comment: @Macanga for submitting multiple forms check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563299/submit-multiple-forms-with-one-submit-button